# Java Apparent Deadlock

Tags: java, c3p0

I had a Db call on start up to get and cache the data and I'm getting to following. I have tried increasing the memory size on on my machine, no luck. Ive been reading about how this is a memory issue here: [Hibernate "APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158560/hibernate-apparent-deadlock-creating-emergency-threads-for-unassigned-pendin).

Here are me connection configurations:

```
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="50" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="2" />
        <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="60" />
        <!--<property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="true" /> -->
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="30" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="1500" />
        <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="1500" />
```

````
2019-12-09 18:31:28 WARN  ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner:624 - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@97c462 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status:
        Managed Threads: 3
        Active Threads: 3
        Active Tasks:
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1bc3e0b (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@14d66f1 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1784e93 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2)
        Pending Tasks:
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@9a5764
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@2e7c1a
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@9ef600
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1312b16
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1ca6e23
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@8704ec
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@164c40a
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@11d372b
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1b6f9dd
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1ee3ce3
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@81f2c0
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@d12254
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@134ec2
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@9e7107
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@15896a6
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@38cfdb
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@57f880
Pool thread stack traces:
        Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0,5,main]
                java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
                java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
                java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1647)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.Prelogin(SQLServerConnection.java:1117)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1038)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
                com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
        Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1,5,main]
                java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
                java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
                java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1647)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.Prelogin(SQLServerConnection.java:1117)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1038)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
                com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
        Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2,5,main]
                java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
                java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
                java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1647)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.Prelogin(SQLServerConnection.java:1117)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1038)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
                com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)```
````

Comment: Have  you checked the number of connections limit for the database? Some implementations will reserve memory proportional to this limit.

Comment: I've often seen this message when the JDBC URL is wrong or the database is down.  I would check those first.

Comment: @schtever I have confirmed both URL is good and DB is up. I’m actually able to extract a few records from the ResultSet. So it is working as, just not getting all of the records.

Comment: @NigelSavage so but I will have to verify that just to be sure. Thanks I’ll report back once I check tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Attempts to acquire new Connections from the database are hanging -- neither succeeding nor failing with an exception for an extended period of time. In the thread dumps, we can see that attempts to get new Connections are blocking on socket read. That is what you want to debug: why is that happening?

One possibility, as Nigel Savage suggests, is that you've hit some resource limit on the server side, perhaps a number of Connections beyond which the server blocks and waits for Connections to be returned before completing new Connections. If this is the case, changing the configuration and maybe capacity on the server side would resolve the issue. An easy way to test this hypothesis would be to choose a much lower pool size (a `maxPoolSize` you are sure the server can easily handle) and see if the `APPARENT DEADLOCK` continues to manifest. If it goes away, probably server side Connection capacity is the culprit.

You could workaround this issue with [`maxAdministrativeTaskTime`](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxAdministrativeTaskTime). But I would not recommend that. It's best to understand and fix the problem than to kludgily force it to go away.

Comment: Hi @Steve Waldman, I've tried adding the following:

<property name="maxAdministrativeTaskTime" value="1" /> AND <property name="numHelperThreads" value="5" />. The application starts extracting the ResultSet and just stops only after 3 records?

Comment: However I'm no longer seeing the Deadlock issue, so... maybe progress? :)

Comment: i’d... not call that progress. i don’t think your just-stops-after-3-secs is related, it’s likely a different issue. but i don’t recommend `maxAdministrativeTaskTime`. did you try a much smaller pool? you really want to underdtand why acquisition of db connections is hanging.

Comment: Yes, I got rid of `maxAdministrativeTaskTime` and now we're here. Still unsure of what the main issue is. I tried lowering the thread pool to 1 and no luck on that either.

Comment: 1 is too small. but with a small thread pool, do you still get `APPARENT DEADLOCK`s?

Comment: Sorry, got caught up at the office. Yes, I'm still getting `APPARENT DEADLOCK`.

Comment: so you are back to trying to understand the hang. are the queries that your application is running very CPU intensive? there may be some hints here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-worker-threads-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15 https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115518/threadpool-wait try to monitor the CPU and other resource use on the server side. the fact that you had a hard time iterating through queries quickly when `maxAdministrativeTaskTime` was set may suggest that the server is getting very bogged down.